# non deprecated way to display a notification in android

Tags: android

I tries to do this:

```
Notification not = new Notification(idIcon, text, System.currentTimeMillis());
PendingIntent pInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, new Intent(ctx, the_class_to_call), 0);

not.setLatestEventInfo(ctx, app_name, text, pInt);
```

But this was deprecated.

I tries to do this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
             new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

But that was deprecated too.

Now, what is the non deprecated way to display a notification in android? 
All the replies i find are this two ways.

My **minSdkVersion: 19**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find a solution for this issue.

I'm using a compatibility library. I use appcompat v7.

appcompat v7 has an actualization for NotificationCompat.Builder. But, when i tries to doing this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
         new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!");
```

The compiler interpret I'm using a appcompat v4 builder.

I fix it doing a cast to appcompat v7 builder.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Hello World!");
```